# Расшифровка писем с разными кодировками.

Tags: pop3, indy, delphi, delphi-7

Добрый день, уважаемые программисты! При получении писем с почтового ящика (через indy) столкнулся со следующей проблемой: в заголовке письма может быть указана одна кодировка, а в теле письма совсем другая кодировка, но явно она там не указана. Возможно ли как-нибудь определить кодировку письма?

Comment: частотный анализ никто не отменял.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кодировка тела письма задается в заголовке Content-type. Например:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=KOI8-R
```

Кодировка заголовка письма задается непосредственно в заголовке (если она отличается от кодировки письма). Например:

```
Subject: =?KOI8-R?Q?=E2=D9=D4=CF=D7=C1=D1_=D4=C5=C8=CE=C9=CB=C1?=
```

Определить кодировку письма без явного указания кодировки может быть довольно сложно (особенно если письмо короткое), учитывая также количество разнообразных кодировок.

Ссылки по теме:

- [модуль на php](http://popoff.donetsk.ua/text/work/libs/a/charset/)
- [Автоматическое определение кодировки текста](http://ivr.webzone.ru/articles/alt_win/index.htm) ALT/WIN
- [Автоматическое определение кодировки текста-2](http://ivr.webzone.ru/articles/defcod_2/index.htm) ALT/WIN/KOI
- ...

ЗЫ В крайнем случае, пользователю можно предложить самому выбрать кодировку.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov потрясающе! Спасибо!:)